# What's the difference between using function and using inline expression to set scope variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I found some differences between executing function and using expression to set variable, specifically, it seems that `ng-if` fails to detect the changes made by expression. I don't understand why.

Pseudo-code:

```
if($scope.editingProfile)
  display edit section
click(backToList button)
  hide edit section
```

The backToList button has a `ng-click` attribute, when I write `ng-click="backToList()"` to execute `$scope.backToList()` in which the `$scope.editingProfile` is set to false it works good. But when I write `ng-click="editingProfile=false"` to set the variable directly, the `ng-if` used to hide the section won't work.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brfbtbd7/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/brfbtbd7/1/

Comment: @PSL it's the same fiddle I put in the question, did you change something but forgot to save?

Comment: oops sorry here it is http://jsfiddle.net/brfbtbd7/2/

Comment: @PSL oh, I see, object problem AGAIN... thank you

Comment: @PSL I mean it seems defining $scope variables as attributes of objects fixes every problem I meet in angular :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `ng-if` directive creates a child scope. So `ng-if="editingProfile"` is the `editing profile` object on the parent which gets inherited to the child scope created by the ng-if. That is what gets displayed @ `Editing {{editingProfile.name}}<br>`. When you do `ng-click="editingProfile=false"` you are actually updating the child scope's inherited version of `editingProfile` which does not gets reflected in the one at the parent. But when you do `ng-click="backToList()"` The function is in the controller and so the `$scope.editingProfile` refers to the one on the controller (parent) hence that change is reflected and ng-if becomes falsy and it hides the content.

You could solve this my adding one more level in the scope property hierarchy.

```
angular.module("testApp", []).controller("editCtrl",
    function ($scope){
      $scope.model = {};
      $scope.model.editingProfile = null;
      $scope.edit = function() {
          $scope.model.editingProfile = {
              name: "test"
          };
      }
      $scope.backToList = function() {
          $scope.model.editingProfile = null;
      }
    }    
)
```

and

```
<div ng-if="model.editingProfile">Editing {{model.editingProfile.name}}
    <br> <a ng-click="backToList()">click to execute function to go back</a>

    <br/> <a ng-click="model.editingProfile=null">click to set variable to go back(NOT working)</a> 
</div>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpw74kzq/)**