# Setting value in controller works, but setting value in angular expression doesn't?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The following code doesn't work -

```
<div ng-init="selected=-1">
<ul ng-repeat="x in arr">
    <li ng-click="selected = $index">...</li>
</ul>
```

When I click on one of the `li`s, the variable selected remains as `-1`. But the following does work -

```
<div ng-init="selected=-1">
<ul ng-repeat="x in arr">
    <li ng-click="setTo($index)">...</li>
</ul>

$scope.setTo = function(index){selected = index;}
```

Why is that? Nothing functional seems to have changed.

Comment: Here is an explanation to your problem.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290982/whats-the-difference-between-using-function-and-using-inline-expression-to-set/26291124#26291124 Answer talks about ng-if here it is ng-repeat both creates child scopes. I wouldn't suggest using `$parent` though..

Comment: One more thing, try not to use `ng-init` for initializing a variable outside ng-repeat. it should actually be done in the controller. If you look at [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) it states `The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.`

Comment: @PSL it was just for the purposes of this example.

Comment: Alright cool.. Just wanted to let you know based on the code posted... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng-repeat` directive creates it's own scope for each item in `arr`, so when expression `selected = $index` is executed, the new property `selected` is created on that scope, at the same time parent scope remains untouched.

Is why your `selected` property does not change in the first case.

Comment: Are you saying that if I do `$parent.selected = $index` it would work?

Comment: Yes, it should help you

Answer (score 3):

Since [the `ngRepeat` directive creates its own scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), you need to refer to `$parent.selected` in the first example:

```
<li ng-click="$parent.selected = $index">
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/9iUgp57KwvrlC3TDO3YC?p=preview